# image processing technique is used to solve

Tags: image-processing, filtering, deconvolution

I have a problem and a solution but i wonder whether my answer is true or not or where did i do wrong thanks for your help-->Question is that-->
A professor of archeology doing research on currency exchange practices became aware that
four Roman coins crucial to his research are listed in the holdings of a museum. Unfortunately,
he learned that the coins had been recently stolen. Good thing on his part is that the museum
keeps photographs of every item in their holdings. Unfortunately, the photos of the coins he is
interested in are blurred to the point where the date and other markings are not readable. The
original camera used to take the photographs is available, as well as other representative coins
from the same era.
You are hired to as an image processing consultant to help the professor to determine whether
computer processing can be utilized to process the images to the point where the professor can
read markings.
Propose a step by step solution to this problem.

Than my solution-->
Firstly, from the coins and cameras that i have
setting that causes blurred photo to occur
and select a start method accordingly.After using the deconvolution method to get rid of the blur, I use a high pass filter to reveal the perimeter of the coin or use tresholding method so that I can reveal the shape of the money.In 2D photography, it is easy to see where the coin is and what pixelles I have to trade.So for example, instead of applying a whole process to the image,
I have been working on the pixeller that has been determined.Then the place where you have the necessary information from the coin I take the gradient in the x-y direction to determine what parts might be from the image.Then i apply dialation to necessary part so that this part can be clear.Once the place has become clearer I get a clear image of the required area with OCR (optical character recognition) or template matching.If you make a comment at least I am very pleased thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, etc. Without any of that, this question just reads as a general requirement (or school assignment), with the expectation that the community is to solve it. And unfortunately this isn't how Stack Overflow works; it's just a bunch of volunteers answering programming questions. Also, it's unclear that this is a programming question, vs general design question. As written, this is currently off-topic as "too broad" and "unclear."

Comment: I changed somethings thak u :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a picture of a single, sharp black dot with the old camera to estimate its PSF.

Now use a supervised deblurring algorithm using that PSF.

---

If the settings of the camera were lost, you can try an reproduce similarly blurred images of the available coins, by varying the focus and optimizing the correlation to the available pictures.